# nginx conf file: Detect if browser language is "de", then redirect to page .... else redirect to other page

Tags: nginx, http-redirect, nginx-config

I want to create a link in a banner to redirect to one of two pages. The link points to `subdomain.example.com/email`. If the browser language is "de" then go to `www.example.de/banner` else go to `www.example.com/banner`. My nginx conf language skills are not good, but I know that any browser language of German has the first two characters are "de" (see https://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes). No other language has this.

```
location /email {
    if $http_accept_language === "de" { return 301 https://www.example.de/banner }
    else { return 301 https://www.example.com/banner}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner and extensible solution uses the `map` directive.

For example:

```
map $http_accept_language $redirect {
    default    https://www.example.com/banner;
    ~de        https://www.example.de/banner;
}

server {
    ...
    location /email {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Answer (score 0):

A similar use case where the locale is to be determined by the browser. There are only two languages offered, so I use `http_accept_language` for this. A standard language has been defined, in this case it is English.

```
map $http_accept_language $lang {
    default en;
    ~de de;
}

server {
   ...
   rewrite ^/$ /$lang/ redirect;
   ...
}
```

After a reload of the configuration the behaviour can be checked with curl.

```
curl -I https://www.your-site.com/  -H "Accept-Language: fr"
curl -I https://www.your-site.com/  -H "Accept-Language: de-CH"
curl -I https://www.your-site.com/  -H "Accept-Language: en-US"
```

Now tests the server repsonse, the header parameter `location` now shows the correct suffix depending on the `Accept-Language`.

```
location: https://www.your-site.com/en/
```

Short note, `Accept-Language` allows a listing using `q-list`, e.g. `de, en-US;q=0.9, es;q=0.1`. The above configuration does not support this. In my case this was not necessary at all.

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales.en