# Choose a different index file for czech language in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to use a different home page for visitors using czech language. I found similar questions ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657614/how-to-rewrite-location-in-nginx-depending-on-the-client-browsers-language), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163428/nginx-conf-file-detect-if-browser-language-is-de-then-redirect-to-page)), I read nginx manual but I cannot make it work. It always serves a default index.html instead of index-cs.html.

```
map $http_accept_language $lang {
  default en;
  ~*cs.* cs;
  ~*cs-CZ.* cs;
  ~*^cs cs;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name lelisoft.com www.lelisoft.com;
  root /var/www/lelisoft.com;
  index index.html;    
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index-$lang.html /index.html;
  }
}
```

And the test usage:

```
curl -v -H "Accept-Language: cs" http://www.lelisoft.com 
*   Trying 162.55.54.132:80...
* Connected to www.lelisoft.com (162.55.54.132) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.lelisoft.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Language: cs
< Content-Length: 473
< Last-Modified: Sun, 25 Jun 2023 09:03:01 GMT
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='eng'>
<head>
```

I am using nginx-full on Debian.

Comment: `try_files $uri $uri/...` means it will try the requested URI first, then the directory `index.html`, *then* any `index-$lang.html` language option, right?  So if you have an (en) `index.html`, it will be chosen before your `index-cs.html`.  Most of the answers you already found deal with this by redirecting always, to the selected language.

Comment: I dont think so. The option /index.html is the last one and /index-$lang.html is before it.

Answer (score 0):

I asked for a help at nginx-users slack and this is the solution:

```
location / {
    index index-$lang.html index.html;
}
```

I have also learnt that I can see how Nginx processes my request with debug log level. You dont need extra package in Debian, the debug is compiled in.

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
```